# jquery: select next input even though in different fieldset

Tags: jquery

I have the following html page:

```
<form action="editProfile" id="userInformation">
<fieldset id="birthdate">
<label><input type="text" id="day" maxlength="2"/>/<input type="text" id="month" maxlength="2"/>/<input type="text" id="year" maxlength="2"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label>Name</label><input type="text" id="name"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to always jump to the next inputfield.
I've tried:

```
$("#birthdate input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
        $(this).next(":input").focus();
    }   
});
```

But that seems to stay within the fieldset. And nextall doesn't seem to work or I'm using it wrong.

edit:
My solution so far:

```
        if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
            if($(this).parent().children().last().attr('id') == $(this).attr("id")){
                $(this).parent().next().find(':input').focus();
            }else{
                $(this).next("input").focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I hadn't come across this issue before; an interesting question (and **+1**) =)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you assign a keydown handler, inside a keydown handler?

Comment: You should avoid use of the keydown handler altogether.  Currently, your coded will cause serious accessibility annoyances if the user wants to revisit one of the previous fields and edit it using the keys.  You should use the HTML5 `oninput` event instead, see [my plugin](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) for a cross-browser implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I also added it in my main post but this is easier to recieve comments.
It seems like there are a lot of sollutions.

My own solution for now:

```
if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
            if($(this).parent().children().last().attr('id') == $(this).attr("id")){
                $(this).parent().next().find(':input').focus();
            }else{
                $(this).next("input").focus();
            }
        }
```

I tried to keep it pretty straightfoward yet flexible I think I could probabily simplify the second if a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a custom method (working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiec/uQdSS/)

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.nextOrParentNext = function(sel){
       var $next = $(this).next(sel);
       if($next.length)
       {
               return $next;
       }
       else
       {
           var $nextParent = $(this).parent().next().find(sel);
           if($nextParent.length)
           {
               return ($nextParent);
           }
       }                  
   };
})(jQuery);

$("#birthdate input:text").keydown(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
        $(this).nextOrParentNext(":input").focus();
    }
});
```

basically, the custom plugin wraps the if/else logic of it being the last item in a fieldset.

Comment: That's a solution ofcourse, but that still requires an if else structure to check if the current input field is the last inputfield in the current section. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#birthdate input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
      var $next = $(this).next(":input");
      if ($next.length == 0) // there are no next fields! try another fieldset
        $next = $(this).closest("fieldset").next("fieldset").find(":input:first");
      $next.focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. Probably not the best solution but it seems to work using the age old modulus operator to cycle the inputs:

```
(function() {
    var inputs = $("#userInformation input[type=text]"),
        i = 0,
        length = inputs.length;

    inputs.keyup(function(e) {
        if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
            i = ++i % length;
            inputs[i].focus();
        }
    });

}());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/DysJe/

I've also made a change to the selector for the inputs. Rather than just picking the `birthdate` fieldset, I pick up all the inputs on the form. Stick these in an array and cycle through focusing on them. I've put everything in it's own closure to keep the variables I created hidden away from everything else.

When it reaches the last input, it will just stop (if `maxlength` is not set) or it will cycle the focus at the beginning again. If you don't want it to cycle, just remove the modulus operator.

**It does have a drawback though** : if the user doesn't focus on the first element then it will ignore this and just go on to focus the second, third, etc.

---

I did a little bit more on this and removed the need for the other variable. This one doesn't work out the next one on the fly, it's set at the very start. Each `input` has its event set to focus the next item in the `inputs` list rather than to the next element `i`. It won't cycle through like the one above but it will move correctly so if the user tabs to the second one it'll progress to the third, etc.

```
(function() {
    var inputs = $("#userInformation input");

    inputs.each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).keyup(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength') && inputs[i + 1]) {
                inputs[i + 1].focus();
            }
        });
    });
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/TQzKS/

You may want to set the `tabIndexes` for your input elements too. I'm not 100% on the order that jQuery returns items in - I think it might be based on the DOM structure. If there's anything unusual in your ordering then you could use the `tabIndex` value of the element to sort the `inputs` list before running the `.each` part.

Oh yes, and in both of these examples I set the `keyup` event so that it moves as soon as I've finished typing.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this recently, which works well:

```
function goToInput(distance) {
    var $input = $(this),
        $inputs = getInputs(),
        currentIndex = $inputs.index($input),
        newIndex = ($inputs.length + currentIndex + distance) % $inputs.length;

    if (currentIndex > -1) {
        $input.blur();
        $inputs.eq(newIndex).focusin().focus();
    }
}

function getInputs() {
    return $('#userInformation :input:visible:enabled');
}

function goToNextInput() {
    goToInput.apply(this, [1]);
}

function goToPreviousInput() {
    goToInput.apply(this, [-1]);
}
```

and then

```
getInputs().keyup(goToNextInput);
```